# How do you change value attribute of an input tag in vue.js onclick?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a component called TitleForm which contains an input and a button and what I simply want is that whenever I click the button to set the value attr to blank. However whenever I try that I get the error `Method "resetValue" has type "object" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?`

TitleForm has a prop so the input value can be set to a specific value whenever it needs to.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="title-form">
    <input type="text" id="title" :value="value" placeholder="Enter title" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="buttons">
    <button @click="resetValue" id="delete-button"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TitleForm',
  props: {
    value: String
  },
  methods: {
    resetValue: {
      function() {
        document.getElementById('title').value = '';
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your function inside an object. The way you have declared it, your `onclick`-Event is trying to call `resetValue` as an object which does not work.

```
methods: {
    resetValue: {
       function() {
          document.getElementById('title').value = '';
       }
    }
}
```

Instead, remove the curly braces and declare `resetValue` as a function:

```
methods: {
    resetValue: function() {
        document.getElementById('title').value = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
methods: {
    resetValue(){
        document.getElementById('title').value = '';
    }
}
```